# Associative array with mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it considered bad practice to use associative arrays in mongodb? I'm curious as to why mongoose doesn't seem to provide this in its Schema definition.

Comment: Mongoose adds "schema" and an associative array implies no schema (as it's a document). If you skip Mongoose, other than not using the reserved `_id` field, you can do it freely (and you could mix and match using native MongoDB access and Mongoose if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "associative array", you mean "Object", that works fine. You can use just regular old "Object" or you can specify specific properties or you can use "mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed" to allow varying types.

```
{
  //regular old javascript/json data types
  created: Date,
  //this works just fine
  statistics: Object,
  //or you can specify the shape of the object
  address: {state: String, line1: String},
  //for the extra features you get with a true subdocument
  nested: [SomeOtherMongooseSchema],
  //Could be array, boolean, number, whatever. Can vary with each document.
  grabBag: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed 
}
```

Comment: Does specifying the shape of the object have any effect on query capabilities? I'm not sure if I lose some mongoose capabilities by using Object. I'm assuming it's field-level operations. Like virtuals, getters, setters, validation, etc.?

Comment: You should still have the ability to query with all the capabilities offered by mongodb. Mongoose really only adds type casting for queries, but to my knowledge other than that doesn't add/remove any features when it comes to queries. Most of the mongoose magic happens during write operations. It's hard for me to generically explain what this can and can't do. Why don't you post a question describing your specific use cases and goals and then folks can make specific suggestions? There is a lot of flexibility with mongodb, obviously.

Comment: You're right, I think I'll have to post a question with my specific use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you use mongoose version > 5.1.0

As specified here in the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps

You can use Map this way to specify an associative array :

```
  myAssociativeArray: {
    type: Map,
    of: String
  }
```

By the way i don't know if you can specify the key type with this syntax